# terminal displays source error message at start up

Tags: bash, macos-sierra, invalid-argument, startup-error

so recently I noticed that every time I open a new terminal window, the terminal would display this message first

```
-bash: source: -/: invalid option
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

I use macbook with MacOS Sierra. I don't know if this relates to the problem or not, but I recently edited ssh config file for a class.

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" . Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly means that you created a syntax error in the file you edited.

The output here is telling you that `source` is invoked incorrectly.  It looks like you have `-/` instead of a proper option (are you missing the rest of a filepath or did you forget to use quotes or otherwise deal with spaces in your filepath?).

```
$ source -/
bash: source: -/: invalid option
source: usage: source filename [arguments]
```

In any case something is mangled in your usage of `source`.  You could run this in your home dir:

```
$ grep "source" ./*
```

To see which files are using `source` in your home directory (note, depending on what you've edited, the problem could be elsewhere). Notably, there are files in `/etc/`/ which would traditionally be using the `source` command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot find the file with the error, and I don't remember which source file I edit. Is there any way to find that file? Or I'm stuck with the annoying error message?

Comment: Did you try `grep`, as I suggested?